# I can't seem to define variables in my code, because document.getElementById( ) won't insert the value in it

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying JavaScript and HTML with a little CSS (that is not required),  and I can't seem to define this variable.

I have the element id with this HTML code:

```
<p class="margin"><b>Got </b>
</p><input type="text" class="margin" id="iGotThis">
<p class="margin"><b> out of </b></p>
<input type="text" class="margin" id="outOfThis">
```

and get it into a variable with js and this code:

```
var made = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
   var total = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
   var perMade = made / total;
```

and I am trying to alert the result with an alert function:

```
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});

   function perFunction() {
    alert(total);
   };
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .margin {
    margin-left: 80px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="margin"><b>Got </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="iGotThis"><p class="margin"><b> out of </b></p><input type="number" class="margin" id="outOfThis">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="margin" onclick="perFunction()">

  <script>
   var iGotThis = document.getElementById("iGotThis").value;
   let outOfThis = document.getElementById("outOfThis").value;
   var perMade = iGotThis / outOfThis;
   
   
// This entire portion has no use for the variables
   var input = document.getElementById("outOfThis");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});
// This is where the useless section ends


   function perFunction() {
    alert(iGotThis.value);
   };
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried just alerting the variable `made` or `total` but just comes up blank. I can't think of a solution so I am hoping someone can help. I am still pretty new to this stuff and can't so everything.

Comment: You have no `id="total"` in the HTML. What is `document.getElementById("total");` supposed to refer to?

Comment: I converted your "full code" into a runnable stack snippet, which reports an error of `TypeError: input is null`. Is this error present in your attempts so far? Please edit the posted code (in the snippet) to accurately reproduce your problem, with the relevant "*[mcve]*" code.

Comment: several issues, no html element with id total, don't use var, you are not making sure make and total are actual number type and not making sure you are not dividing by 0

Comment: I fixed that, it was no use for getting the variable, just to have an ```on event``` for an ```Enter``` press. Can you help now? @Barmar

Comment: You're reading the values and performing the calculations when the script is initially loaded (which is a long time before the user types anything and triggers `perFunction`). There's probably a pile of duplicates around.

Comment: @Quentin so add an event listener?

Comment: You've already got an event listener. Move the code that reads the values inside it.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, that works with the individual variables. But my goal is to divide one by the other, and when I try to alert that variable, it doesn't even alert anything.

Comment: So put the code that reads the first text box inside the function. Then put the code which reads the second text box inside the function. Then you will have both values that the user has typed. So move the code which does the division inside the function. Then finally alert it … still inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

there is no ID as "total" in the HTML code. Please check that

Comment: I fixed that, but it still won't put anything in the variable. Can you help now?